# Blueprint can't pull a function from a Widget

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints

I am working on a project and I am stumped on something and it is taking me to long to fix this issue.
[image]
As seen above I am this is where I am, what I need to do is set up a widget text that changes by what the player does. The problem is I have been following this tutorial, which is found here -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILtVovyqrmY&t=1097s It starts at 16:09 for the starting point of my problem and ends at 19:42, and I have somehow got stuck.
[image]
As seen above he can easily pull the function out of the widget but when I try it won't allow me too. Can someone help me please?

(Note: I have the name for the character changed for my version of the game compared to the tutorial and the text is different because of the video maker changing the name and moving it somewhere.)

Below here is a number of screenshots that show the game and the main concern.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why is Your WBP_BarkText a widget of type "Editor Utility Widget" (Light Blue widget blueprint color)? It should be of type "User Widget" (Dark Blue widget blueprint color), you can find it by right clicking in the Content Browser and hovering over "User Interface" and then clicking "Widget Blueprint". Go back to the vid and redo the steps after the widget blueprint was created and use the correct type of widget blueprint, it should work afterwards, good luck! :)

Here's a screenshot for clarification. [image: Widget Blueprint you need to use]

Comment: Sorry for the long wait to respond, but thanks! It worked!